# Command-line incremental backup tools

Tags: command-line, backup, compression

Which command line backup tool(s) has the best compression ratio? I want to backup my entire system, including media files, text files etc.

I found [this list](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backup_programs#Console) on the Arch wiki site but I don't know how these tools compare to each other and which one would offer the best compression ratio overall. I realize that different tools might give better results for specific file types, but which tool and using which settings would result in the smallest archive given a mix of various input files?

Comment: covering all bases I see.

Comment: This question isn't opinion based; it's asking for an objective metric (compression ratio).

Comment: so I used tar so far, which is relatively slow

Answer (score 1):

The highest compression ratio also has some important drawbacks and is usually not recommended.

For a backup solution, it is often important to have a fast restore.

The compression ratio you are able to achieve depends on your data and the compression tool you are using. `xz` provides one of the highest compression ratios:

```
xz -z -c -9 -e /dev/sda2 > /path/file.xz
```

will compress your disk device to stdout (`-c`) with the highest compression ratio (`-9`) and the extreme switch (`-e`). This will take a very long time.

Another way to have good compression ratios and also a fast restore is using a compression-enabled file system like BTRFS, where you can store for example `rsync` backups.

To mount a compressed BTRFS volume:

```
mount /dev/sda2 -t btrfs -o noatime,nodiratime,compress=lzo /path
```

This is pretty convenient, because you don't need to deal with compression (it is automatically done by the filesystem) and have fast access to your backed-up data.

Comment: good point about the drawbacks and great example, I believe the reason why xz gained traction was because bzip2, while having a greater compression ratio than gzip, worked much slower